# Need help inputting data in excel columns from other columns

Tags: excel

If I had data in rows A to E as seen below in the table. Some of the values can be NA. IN column F if i wanted to input data from columns A to E in a way that if data in A exists use that otherwise if data in B exists use that otherwise until column E. If none of them have any values return NA. I would like to automate this where somewhere I just specify the order for example A, B, C, D and E OR A, C, E, D, B and the values in F update according to the reference table

Reference : C - B - A - E - D

| a | b | c | d | e | f |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 |  |  | 4 |  | 3 |
|  |  |  | 2 |  | 2 |
|  | 7 |  |  | 1 | 7 |
|  |  |  |  |  | NA |
| 1 | 4 | 2 | 4 | 2 | 2 |
|  |  |  | 4 | 2 | 2 |

Comment: How your last two result is `2,2`. It should be `1` and `4`.

Comment: The preference is c before anything, so if all values from a to e exist use the value in c. Similarly e takes preference over d

Answer (score 0):

Use `FILTER()` with `@` operator.

```
=@FILTER(A2:E2,A2:E2<>"","NA")
```

For dynamic array approach (spill results automatically), try-

```
=BYROW(A2:E7,LAMBDA(x,INDEX(FILTER(x,x<>"","NA"),1,1)))
```

[image]

Comment: This is just filtering out the datat, I wanted the output in row f to follow c b a e d. Here in row 6 you see c has a value of 6 which should be preferred to anything else. But the output with your code just prints the first non zero instance from the left